# return a variable from .click() javascript function

Tags: javascript

First of all excuse for my weak english, I try to use the following javascript code and I want to return id variable and use it in other function, but it seem does not work correctly and does not return it, can someone help me out writting this

```
var idcb = $('.box').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    return id;
});
```

I want to use var idcb in this function :

```
$(".hs").click(function() {    
    $(idhs).slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

for that to work, the jquery `click` implementation would need to know that the function you pass it returns a value, and that it itself should return that value - which isn't the case.

instead, you could use some closure magic to do this easily. try this:

```
var idcb;
$('.box').click(function() {
    idcb = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: your code works good , and i had made a mistake, but there is another problem, when i click the variable would be set, but should click another time,to work correct, how could hide function and click fuction excute continuesly?

Comment: you could call one from the other. i'm not entirely sure that is what you want though as your question was somewhat unclear...

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an anonymous function to an event handler, you cannot return a value from this type of function. The solution is to use closures to get around this :

```
var idcb = null;
$('.box').click(function() {
    idcb = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

The variable idcb will always be set to the id of the last .box that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The function is given as a parameter to the click function and is run asynchronously when the user clicks on an element.  So you can't return a value directly, since the function won't be run immediately.  You can look up the id value another way, or pass it to a function to work with instead of returning it, or just do this:

```
var idcb = $('.box').click(function() {

   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   $(id).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you are trying to. However, what you can do is use a variable that is accessible by both functions to share values between them.

```
var icdb = 'test';

function a() {
    icdb = 'another value';
}

function b() {
    console.log(icdb);
}

a();
b();
```

You could also call `b` from `a` and pass the variable as argument:

```
function a() {
    b('test');
}

function b(icdb) {
    console.log(icdb);
}

a();
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable `idcb` contains the click handler !

you need to declare the vriable outside the handler and assign to it inside to make this work:

```
 var idcb = null;

 // ... whatever
 $('.box').click(function() {
     idcb = $(this).attr('id');

     return true; // return 'true' from an event handler to indicate successful completion
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/S4jrY/3/)

```
var id=null;
$('.box').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
});

$(".hs").click(function() {
    $("#"+id).slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i used your code, but it didn't work, i put an alert function in the first function ,it shows the true value but when i put alert outside it, it shows null value, How can i fix that?

Comment: You have a click event, so you need to click on .box before you sets the value.

Comment: If you just want to get the id of .box then can you do $(".box").attr("id"); Can you post your code at jsfiddle so I can se what you trying to do?

Comment: here is url project, when you click in close icon, box hides, but should click the close icon 2 times, how could use it with 1 time click?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the an object as a reference to the click function 
and change the value from the callback. Another option is using closures 
The caveat to this jsfiddle is that you have to call a .box element first.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6B73/2/

```
var idcb = {};
$('.box').click(idcb, function (event) {
        event.data.value = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(idcb.value);
 });

$('.hs').click(function() {    
   $('#'+idbc.value).slideToggle("slow");  
});
```

Comment: thnx, it's good but i want to run 2 function continuesly, mean first get id for .box div and immediately run .hs function and slide it's section,how?

Comment: do you really need the .hs call? Couldn't you just do the sliding inside the .box click? You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D6B73/3/). At that point though you wouldn't beed the idcb variable though,

Comment: here is the url: http://itsun.ir/test/,, my goal is when a user clicks on close icon, the .box div hide, .hs is just handle hiding .box div, do you have a better idea to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
$(".hs").on('click', function() {
   var id = $('.box').attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
```